# Passing props to a component with local state vs state lifting vs redux - recommendation

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have two components a chart rendering a single crypto pair price and an orderbook. 
Both have local state. 
I would like the change of a crypto pair on the chart trigger the change on the orderbook - showing the orderbook of the pair chosen on the chart. 
This means both components need to share current pair in their state.

My questions:

Can I pass a prop with the crypto pair to the orderbook component which already has a local state? 
Is the above impossible/possible/goes against the react philosophy or what would be the problem? 
Should I lift the state instead and keep the state local only to the chart component? 
Or perhaps redux is the best option and I can't run away from it?

Comment: React believes in composition, so lifting state is preferred and if the state to be lifted can be used in other places as well or it is application state then it should be in redux store. More info [here](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#organizing-state-only-redux-state)

Comment: When the job involve sharing data between 2 or more components easy answer: redux. Don't dig much more than that.

Comment: Thank you guys. Redux sounds really tempting here, as I have more components and similar approach is requested for some of them.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending a props to your child component, If the data in your parent component changes it will send the new data and and your child component will re-rendered with the new data. Also if you were using Redux,  they will behave same.

My suggestion would be if it is only between these who components you can just send it as a props and that will do it. However if this data should be shared with other components as well you might want to use Redux.